# List directories (with information)

Tags: algorithm, c, reinventing-the-wheel, file, homework

For part of a project, I was given this directive:

> The “ls” command will require you to use directory functions to list
>   out what the filenames are in the directory. Functions required to
>   make a “ls” command work are included in the `<dirent.h>` header file (
>   man dirent ). You will need to open a directory and iterate through
>   the directory until you hit the end and display the filenames in that
>   current directory.
>   Now, the requirement for this piece of the lab requires an example of
>   “ls –l” where you display most of the inode information on the file.

I've implemented this below.  It seems to mimic `ls -la` quite well, even for all the edge cases I've been testing.

**ls.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifndef streq
#define streq(x, y) (strcmp((x), (y)) == 0)
#endif

/*
 * This function takes a mode value and a char array
 * and puts into the char array the file type and the
 * nine letters that correspond to the bits in mode.
 * NOTE: It does not code setuid, setgid, and sticky
 * codes
 */
char* mode_to_letters(int mode)
{
    const int STR_SIZE = 11;             // size of mode string + terminator
    char *str = malloc(STR_SIZE);
    memcpy(str, "----------", STR_SIZE); // default

    if (S_ISDIR(mode))  str[0] = 'd';    // directory
    if (S_ISCHR(mode))  str[0] = 'c';    // char devices
    if (S_ISBLK(mode))  str[0] = 'b';    // block device

    if (mode & S_IRUSR) str[1] = 'r';    // 3 bits for user
    if (mode & S_IWUSR) str[2] = 'w';
    if (mode & S_IXUSR) str[3] = 'x';

    if ( mode & S_IRGRP ) str[4] = 'r';  // 3 bits for group
    if ( mode & S_IWGRP ) str[5] = 'w';
    if ( mode & S_IXGRP ) str[6] = 'x';

    if ( mode & S_IROTH ) str[7] = 'r';  // 3 bits for other
    if ( mode & S_IWOTH ) str[8] = 'w';
    if ( mode & S_IXOTH ) str[9] = 'x';

    return str;
}

//  returns pointer to username associated with uid, uses getpw()
char* uid_to_name( uid_t uid )
{
    struct passwd *pw_ptr = {0};
    char *numstr = malloc(10);

    if ((pw_ptr = getpwuid(uid)) == NULL)
    {
        sprintf(numstr,"%d", uid);
        return numstr;
    }
    else
        return pw_ptr->pw_name ;
}

//  returns pointer to group number gid. used getgrgid(3)
char* gid_to_name(gid_t gid)
{
    struct group *grp_ptr = NULL;
    char *numstr = malloc(10);

    if ((grp_ptr = getgrgid(gid)) == NULL)
    {
        sprintf(numstr, "%d", gid);
        return numstr;
    }
    else
        return grp_ptr->gr_name;
}

// display the info about 'filename'.  The info is stored in struct at *info_p
void show_file_info(char *filename, struct stat *info_p)
{
    char *modestr = mode_to_letters(info_p->st_mode);

    fprintf(stdout, "%s %2d %-9s %-6s %5lld %.12s %s\n",
            modestr,
            info_p->st_nlink,
            uid_to_name(info_p->st_uid),
            gid_to_name(info_p->st_gid),
            info_p->st_size,
            4 + ctime(&info_p->st_mtime),
            filename);

    free(modestr);
}

void dostat(char *filename, char* suffix)
{
    struct stat info = {0};
    char temp[PATH_MAX] = "";
    snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%s/%s", suffix, filename);

    if (stat(temp, &info) == -1)
        perror(temp);
    else
        show_file_info(filename, &info);
}

//  list files in directory called dirname
void do_ls(char dirname[])
{
    DIR *dir_ptr = NULL;            // the directory
    struct dirent *direntp = NULL;  // each entry

    if ((dir_ptr = opendir(dirname)) == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "my_ls: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
    else
    {
        while ((direntp = readdir(dir_ptr)))
        {
            dostat(direntp->d_name, dirname);
        }
        closedir(dir_ptr);
    }
}

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    if (ac == 1)
        do_ls( "." );
    else
        while (--ac)
        {
            printf("%s:\n", *++av);
            do_ls(*av);
            fputc('\n', stdout);
        }
}
```

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Don't used dynamic memory when the stack will do just fine

`uid_to_name()` and `gid_to_name()` may end up `malloc`ing the returned string. This only complicates things (caller has to free) and decreases performance. Your code could leak memory because of that:

> ```
> fprintf(stdout, "%s %2d %-9s %-6s %5lld %.12s %s\n",
>         modestr,
>         info_p->st_nlink,
>         uid_to_name(info_p->st_uid),
>         gid_to_name(info_p->st_gid),
>         info_p->st_size,
>         4 + ctime(&info_p->st_mtime),
>         filename);
> ```

You've only freed `modestr`.

So why not pass in the buffer instead?

```
char* uid_to_name(uid_t uid, char* buffer, size_t bufSize);
char* gid_to_name(gid_t gid, char* buffer, size_t bufSize);
```

Then those could be called with a stack buffer:

```
char uid_name_buf[10];
char gid_name_buf[10];

fprintf(stdout, "%s %2d %-9s %-6s %5lld %.12s %s\n",
        modestr,
        info_p->st_nlink,
        uid_to_name(info_p->st_uid, uid_name_buf, sizeof(uid_name_buf)),
        gid_to_name(info_p->st_gid, gid_name_buf, sizeof(gid_name_buf)),
        info_p->st_size,
        4 + ctime(&info_p->st_mtime),
        filename);
```

A little more verbose, but not really, since for the current code to be fully correct you'd have to `free` the returned pointer if it was allocated. The same thing can be applied to `mode_to_letters()`.

### Miscellaneous:

- Mark pointers you are only reading from as `const`, specially function parameters! This is very important to convey the correct intent!
- Prefer `snprintf` since it will check for overflow - you're not using it consistently.
- Every function but main could be `static`, but I'm just being pedantic.
- `streq` macro was never used, so could be removed.
- I see some minor inconsistencies with how `()` are spaced - some have extra whitespace padding and others don't - [ClangFormat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) to the rescue?.
- `int main(int ac, char *av[])` - you've misspelled `argc` and `argv` `;)`